# Считать 2 строки из файла в массив char[]

Tags: массивы, char, файлы, c++

Здравствуйте.
Такая проблема, как только не пытался ее решать.
Нужно считать 2 строки из файла в массив `char[]`
Вот последняя удачная попытка:

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int k,m,i=0,j=0;
        char a[100];
        char b[100];
        string c;
        string d;
        ifstream fin;
        FILE* fp;
        fp=open("input.txt","r")
        getline(fin,c,'\n');
        getline(fin,d);
        cout<<c;
        cout<<c[12];
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<d;
        cout<<d[0];
        fin.close();
        _getch();
```

До нее была такая версия, которая читала первую строку, вторую, но выводила еще кучу всяких иероглифоф:

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int k,m,i=0,j=0;
        char a[100];
        char b[100];
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("input.txt");
        while(!cin.eof())
        {
            fin.get(a[i]);
            if (a[i]==' ')continue;
            else if(a[i]=='\n')break;
            else {cout<<a[i]<<setw(2);i++;}
        }
        cout<<endl;
        while(!cin.eof())
        {
            fin.get(b[i]);
            if (b[i]==' ')continue;
            else {cout<<b[i]<<setw(2);i++;}

    }
    fin.close();
    _getch();
}
```

Научите, пожалуйста, нормально считывать строки(вариант с `getline()` не подойдет, нужен именно массив `char[]`)
Заранее спасибо!

```
Вот код который считывает именно числа

    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k,m,i,j=0;
    int a[100];
    int b[100];

    i=0;
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%i",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]==(char)'\n'){a[i]=0;break;}
        else if (a[i]!=' '){cout<<a[i]<<" ";i++;}
    }
    i=0;
    cout<<endl;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%i",&b[i]);
        if(feof(fp))break;
        else if (b[i]!=' '){cout<<b[i];i++;}
    }
    fclose(fp);
    _getch();
}
```

Но он считывает в первый массив a[] весь файл, то есть
`if(a[i]=='\n'){a[i]=0;break;}` не дейсвует
а мне нужно два массива интов, причем для такого:
1 33 44
a[0]=1, a[1]=33, a[2]=44
Но при использовании массива char считывается каждый символ в отдельную переменную

Дана задача использовать именно массивы. Задача такая считать первую строку в массив a[] a[1]=1 a[2]=32 ... Вторую - массив b[] b[1]=2 b[2]=56 ...

Comment: Во-первых, на C++ пользуются не массивами символов, а строками. Кроме того, в чём проблема считать при помощи getline, а потом получить массив символов из строки?

Comment: Просто попробуйте использовать `fgets()` из `stdio.h` для чтения массивов символов (см. `man fgets`).

Comment: @Саша Калюжный, что именно Вы хотите сделать в своей последней программе?

Прочесть все числа из одной строки? 

Тогда надо прочесть строку, а потом уже из нее извлечь числа. В этом случае посмотрите `man strtol` или `man fmemopen` (последнее для Linux).

Или можно использовать `string` и `stringstream` из С++.

Comment: Я не против, но дана задача использовать именно массивы.
Задача такая считать первую строку в массив a[] a[1]=1 a[2]=32 ...
Вторую - массив b[] b[1]=2 b[2]=56 ...

Comment: @Саша Калюжный, такая функция должна помочь выбирать числа из строки

    int
    str2iarr (const char *str, int arr[], int asize, char **ep)
    {
      int n = 0;
    
      for (; n < asize; n++) {
        arr[n] = strtol(str, ep, 10);
        if (str == *ep || !isspace(**ep))
          break;
        str = *ep + 1;
      }
    
      return n;
    }

Только на переполнение числа не проверяю. 

Просто вызывайте ее для каждой строки и проверяйте, например так

     if (**ep && !isspace(**ep)) printf ("error input: [%s]\n", *ep);

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Числа-то я понял как выбирать, мне интересно прочитать в 2 массива
int 2 строки из файла. Массив a[]-первая строка чисел, массив b[]-вторая строка чисел.

Comment: @Саша Калюжный, стандартными средствами языка (библиотеки) никак. Точнее, я не знаю.

Если интересно, могу всю программу, выполняющую Ваше задание в ответе привести. Читает первую строку, выбирает из нее числа в `a[]`, потом вторую и числа в `b[]`. Для выборки чисел вызывает функцию `str2iarr()` из моего комментария.

Но, может я не до конца понимаю, что Вам непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Если второй вариант правильно работает, то сперва надо всем элементам символьных массивов дать начальное значение (инициализировать переменные). Для этого делаем так:

```
char a[100]='\0';
char b[100]='\0';
```

\0 - "пустой символ". В консоли он никак не отображается. После этого код должен работать верно.

Comment: Второй вариант работает почти правильно, но даже при начальном значении '/0' в консоли пишется еще 10 символов

                                   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8
       ■       Z ☼ ╙ v Y № ╪ v ╨ ╬ @   8   (     р ¤
 ↕ @   ☺       0

Comment: все заработало, я исправил
while(!cin.eof()) на while(!fin.eof())
но остались лишние пробелы. Как он тих избавитьяс?

Comment: лишние пробелы во второй строке? меняем во 2м цикле i  на j:

      while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.get(b[j]);
        if (b[j]==' ')continue;
        else {cout<<b[j]<<setw(2);j++;}
    }

Comment: И еще вопросик.
Как сделать, чтобы массив 1 2 43 44
был записан как a[0]=1, a[1]=2, a[2]=43, a[3]=44;

Comment: Правильно я понимаю: В исходном фале записаны числа, их надо считать в массив? тогда вот так:
    
    int a[100] = 0; //раз считываем числа, то делаем массив числовых переменных
    int i = 0; //инициализируем переменную управления циклом
    while (fin >> a[i]) { //fin >> a[i] будет считывать 1 число из файла пока файл не закончится
        //производим действия над считанной переменной
    }

Важно: этот метод не работает если в файле будет хотя бы 1 буква, числа могут быть разделены пробелом / знаком табуляции / знаком переноса строки